# Android: EditText always remembers inputted Text

Tags: android

I have an EditText field and a check box inside an activity. What I want is, whenever the checkbox is checked, the inputted text inside the EditText field will be saved and everytime the user opens the app, the text he/she enters the last time are still there.

How am I able to perform that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Roughly, it's a non-db storage of simple primitive objects that you want remembered by your application.

Answer (score 2):

Call and commit to the SharedPreferences in the OnStop(), and call it again in onCreate. Something like this:

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
   }

   private void LoadPreferences(){
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
String strSavedMem2 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM2", "");
textSavedMem1.setText(strSavedMem1);
textSavedMem2.setText(strSavedMem2);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could either use **shared preferences** if it is some user related info or probably use **sqlite database** to store values and retreive them on Activity load.

Cheers,
Richie

Answer (score 1):

Using Shared prefernces save the text. And while launching the application or Activity get the dat and store in the edit text field.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to save the text in the EditText whenever it's altered into [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Then you can pull the saved text back out of SharedPreferences in your onCreate or onResume method in your Activity.